# Kill C++ process in python using ctrl + C

Tags: python, c++

I have a python wrapper for a c++ program using Python.h
In C++, the code contains an infinite loop as service:

```
for (;;) {
  ...
}
```

The python wrapper invokes this service and jumps into this loop. When I call <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, the program can't be killed. (It seems that the python program has been killed and the c++ program not)

How can I kill both of the python and c++ program using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

Comment: If your python program is starting the C++ service, you could try interrupting SIGTERM signal in python and gracefully exit the C++ process

Answer (score -1):

If you have pid of the child process, you can kill it using `os.kill(pid, sig)`.
To launch it when your python exits, you may add `.atexit` handler.

Comment: I don't know the pid. All the setup has been done inside python.h